# Display table html confusion

Tags: html, css

so I'm trying to build a layout with a few basic things: a header, that has a fixed size; and content, that is only allowed to be as big as the page - any overflow should just scroll inside that.

I can't seem to get the inner div to only scroll and get overflow to stay.

CSS:

```
body {
    display:table;
    width: 100%;
}         
#content-body,#header {
    display:table-row;
}

 #content {
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
        header here
    </div>

    <div id="content-body">
            <div id="content">
             <--   Need this to scroll -->
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W43UV/4/)

I'd only like to get this work with just css and html

someone please help me! I'm kind of confused as to why this is not working

Comment: `display: table` is a thoroughly wrong way to do that.  Use `position: absolute` and stretch the content.

Comment: Do you know how high your header is, or is it a flexible / changing height?

Comment: header is a constant height but the content div needs to be 100% - the header height

Comment: @CSgoose, it seems you've asked a couple of questions on SO already and didn't mark any of them as answered. It would be nice if you accepted a correct answer on your question if there is one, otherwise people will not be as willing to help you in the future.]

Comment: When my problem gets fixed I will mark one as accepted

Comment: Fair enough. I also just noticed that you did mark one, apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `display: table` at all, that's not going to do the trick for you.

Since you know the height of the header, all you really have to do is give the `#content` a `position: absolute` (which is relative to the `body` tag by default if it's not wrapped in anything with a `relative` position). Then you can just stretch it from where it needs to start (bottom of the header) all the way to the bottom doing this:

```
#content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px; /* or whatever your header height is */
    bottom: 0;
}
```

See my jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/W43UV/5/

(I set the padding and margin of the `body` to `0` to prevent the `top` offset to be messed up)

Comment: Here's an alternative solution that might not be exactly suitable to your problem, but it's sometimes useful in similar situations: http://jsfiddle.net/W43UV/6/. It relies on the browser's scrollbar instead of adding one to the div, but it does roughly the same thing you asked. Not sure if this would be useful but you never know.

Comment: Hmm I forgot to add that body must have margin: 0 auto; doesn't seem to work with this rule because now content doesn't have the correct margin

Comment: As long as the top and bottom are 0 (which you also have), this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Seems the right margin is lost on the right, but if I position body relative everything works then the outermost div has a scroll on the height of the header

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean, could you put that in a jsfiddle too?

Comment: I realized my mistake I was making #content div height 100%, ugh one of those problems that you stare at for hours then go duhhh. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

sandbox.css:

```
#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #ff4200;
}
#content-body {
    width: 100%;
}
#content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: #0042ff;
}
```

sandbox.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sandbox.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            header here
        </div>
        <div id="content-body">
            <div id="content">
                <-- Need this to scroll -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: With the `#content` set to `height: 40px`, how will this stretch to the bottom of the screen?

Comment: #content height cannot be fixed